# C++ character counter

Tags: c++

I need to design a character counter, whenever I enter single char. it gives me the next one in succession e.g. enter A, it shows B, Z-->A for both lower and Upper letters. only using (for loop)
What went wrong?
The characters doesn't show in order I mean whenever I enter a letter it's random response giving me a random number that hasn't any function of the program the body looks acceptable but in turns of internal details something isn't going the way I wanted to be. Here's my code:

```
char count[256];
int size = 0;

for ( c != 0; ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) ; c++ )
{
    size += count[c];
}

return size;

return 0;
```

Comment: Post your code here as text, never post images of code. And explain what your actual problem is. A homework dump is not a valid question. What specific problem did you run into?

Comment: Please, edit the question to add a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a question about a specific problem. As you expect quality answer, we expect quality questions.

Comment: Along with what the others have stated to improve your question, it is unclear what the desired behavior of your code should be. Are you trying to count the number of alphabetic characters in a string? Are you trying to count the number of each character in the string? As far as I can tell your code seems to be doing neither of those, because at minimum it is fundamentally flawed because you are passing a `char` into the function which in no way could represent a string.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot  I'm really sorry for posting a question that it seems  " dump& unclear" for you but this was my first question I've asked in Stackoverflow,com however, THIS IS THE CODE YOU HAVE ASKED ME TO WRITE <<<<

Comment: #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char StringLength (char c)
{
    char count[256];
    int size = 0;

    for ( c != 0; ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) ; c++ )
    {
    size += count[c];
    }
    return size;
}
int main()
{
    char c;
    int size = 0 ,length;
    cout << "Enter your string of characters: ";
    cin >> c;
    size = StringLength (c);
    cout << "The total number of characters entered is: " << size << endl;

    return 0;
}

Comment: @AdamMuman no problem. Just add your code to the question. I've been a beginner on stackoverflow once. Knowing how to ask a question properly is as important as being able to answer those questions.

Comment: i can't  write the letters are limited in the chat.

Comment: @AdamMuman Please, don't post code in comments. They are not meant for that, and it's in fact, unreadable. Edit the question instead.

Comment: Do you find the code clear @GuillaumeRacicot I mean the alignment is so mixed up!>

Comment: Oh, I see, wait a sec,@Carcigenicate

Comment: @AdamMuman No. Comments are really not meant for posting code. You can change the text of the question using the edit button. You can then add your code and format it properly

Comment: What do u think about it? @GuillaumeRacicot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using ASCI codes will be helpfull here 
for e.g

```
char alphabet ;
cout  <<"Enter alphabet"<<endl;
cin>>alphabet ;
int a = (int) alphabet;
a++;
cout<<"Next alphabet is :"<<(char)a<<endl ;
```

Comment: i would recommend the use of ASCI codes as they are simple and will prevent your code to create  a jargon .

Comment: Check for rollover condition, otherwise you'd get '[' after 'Z', and '{' after 'z'
Again, @Adam Muman needs to figure out where and how to check for this condition, and what to do in that case.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning :D

Comment: @YoushaArif It is **ASCII** with two I's instead of ASCI.

Comment: Hello Yousha Arif sorry for not responding. I hope you are doing well . your answer helped me alot back in 2017, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Take your input
- Check if it is an alphabet
- Check if it is a 'z' or 'Z', if so, make it an 'a', or 'A' (hint: use ascii codes and a little arithmetic)
- Else add a character to it
- Print

Comment: Thanks for the support but I want it to be whenever I enter a letter it gives me the following letter in order e.g cin>> a;   the program should give me "b".

Comment: That's precisely what my algorithm does. Except that I gave you an algorithm and not spoon-fed you your homework. ;-)
You're supposed to find out how to do the little bits yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Pranav for your kind support I know , sorry for the late response.It's more than 2 year now, I want to tell in 2017 your answer was correct and helped me to build my passion of programing.